# no such file to load -- mechanize

Tags: ruby, shoes

Code:

```
Shoes.setup do
  gem 'mechanize'
end

require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
```

Running Shoes on it says:

```
no such file to load -- mechanize
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did:

```
sudo gem install mechanize
```

and the following seems to be working:

```
Shoes.setup do
  gem 'mechanize'
end

require 'mechanize'
```

It says 'Building native extensions' and is taking forever, but seems to be the norm according to [hackety.org](http://hackety.org/2008/05/08/clearingUpTheWholeShoesAndRubyGemsDeal.html).

Answer (score 1):

`rubygems` needs to be required before any gems.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

Shoes.setup do
  gem 'mechanize'
end
```