# Why can't Shoes::Setup#gem find my gem?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Despite reading what has been written on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825331/where-to-put-ruby-gem-files-so-that-shoes-setup-can-find-them) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548657/shoes-and-gems) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512502/using-ruby-libraries-and-gems-with-a-shoes-app), I still can't get these lines to work for me:

```
Shoes.setup do
  gem 'statemachine'
end

require 'rubygems'
require 'statemachine'
```

I have run "sudo gem install statemachine" successfully and copied the gem by hand to ~/.shoes/ to no avail so far.

I am using ruby 1.8 under Mac OS X 10.5.8 and the gem I'm trying to use has no dependencies and works perfectly when invoked from Ruby.

I am trying to grok the Shoes and Gem code to solve this mystery but could use some help from experienced programmers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That code works fine for me.  Shoes should go out on its own and get the gem if needed.  Your problem may be that you copied the gem over.  Try deleting it from ~/.shoes/ and running the code again.